# Array of arrays of arrays in qw representation in Perl

Tags: perl, data-structures

Hello I'd like to form a data structure like this:

```
my @AoAoA = (
   [ qw/ [a b] [c d] [e f] / ],
   [ qw/ [r t] [m n] [k l] / ],
   [ qw/ [z x] [b a] [p u] / ]
    );
```

In this structure which I call array of arrays of arrays in qw representation, AoAoA for short, when I want to access the first array's first array's first value:

```
my $first_elt = @{$AoAoA[0]}[0];# supposed to be [a b]
my $first_val = @{$first_elt}[0];# supposed to be 'a'

print "$first_val\n";
```

it prints nothing. How sould I arrange it so I can access that value correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`qw` is short for *quote words*. It will implicitly quote every non-space substring for you, which is often very useful. But you can't add complex data structures using the same construct

Your assignment

```
my @AoAoA = (
    [ qw/ [a b] [c d] [e f] / ],
    [ qw/ [r t] [m n] [k l] / ],
    [ qw/ [z x] [b a] [p u] / ]
)
```

is the same as

```
my @AoAoA = (
    [ '[a', 'b]', '[c', 'd]', '[e', 'f]' ],
    [ '[r', 't]', '[m', 'n]', '[k', 'l]' ],
    [ '[z', 'x]', '[b', 'a]', '[p', 'u]' ]
)
```

which is unlikely to be what you want. Instead you must use `qw//` to define *only the strings* in your structure, like this

```
my @AoAoA = (
    [ [ qw/ a b / ], [ qw/ c d / ], [ qw/ e f / ] ],
    [ [ qw/ r t / ], [ qw/ m n / ], [ qw/ k l / ] ],
    [ [ qw/ z x / ], [ qw/ b a / ], [ qw/ p u / ] ]
)
```

Then you can write

```
my $first_elt = $AoAoA[0][0];    # ['a', 'b']
my $first_val = $first_elt->[0]; # 'a'
```

Or you can use just

```
my $first_val = $AoAoA[0][0][0]; # 'a'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Instead of using qw inside the second degree arrays i.e. [ [ qw/ a b /] , writing directly [ [a,b] (without quotes) works too, but only until the [m,n] element i.e. I have to qw that element. The elements following that I don't have to qw, only that element I have to qw. If that element didn't need qw, then it would be quite fine.

Comment: @Romario Always `use strict; use warnings 'all'`. That way, using directly `a, b`  (without quotes) won't work, but that's a good thing. The reason `m` isn't working without the quotes is that `m` is the match operator (`y` wouldn't work as well).

Comment: @Romano: It would *not* be "fine" because that means you don't have `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place at the top of your program. These are essential for *every* Perl program you write, and you should start including them immediately. Even if you omit these measures, you will see eighteen warning messages `Unquoted string "a" may clash with future reserved word` etc. with any recent version of Perl. Just because something appears to work doesn't mean it should be written like that.

Comment: @Dada thank you for the input. The 'm' interfering with the m operator is right; I've tried changing m to some other char and it worked. So,  using chars without quotes is not an option. I have to think of other ways to represent AoAoA concisely.

Comment: @Borodin You're correct, in that form it's not totally fine. It was an experiment to see if it would work. Anyway because of the clash with the one-word operator names such as 'm' it didn't work. Now I have to think of other ways to  represent that AoAoA.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work since inside `qw` you can't use the square brackets. so the elements in your qw are "`[a`", "`b]`", ... .

What you probably want is:

```
my @AoAoA = (
   [ [qw/a b/], [qw/c d/], [qw/e f/] ],
   [ [qw/r t/], [qw/m n/], [qw/k l/] ],
   [ [qw/z x/], [qw/b a/], [qw/p u/] ]
    );
```

Trying to make it shorter:

```
my @AoAoA = map {[map {[split ' ']} split /,/]} (
   "a b,c d,e f",
   "r t,m n,k l",
   "z x,b a,p u"
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The short version seems quite plausible as it shortens the representation fairly.

Comment: @Romario: The "short version" is dreadful: it sacrifices readability for conciseness. Since the whole purpose of conciseness is better readability it's a pointless effort.

Comment: *"inside `qw` you can't use the square brackets"* This isn't true. Square brackets are fine inside `qw//` but they behave no differently from any other non-space character.

Comment: @
@Borodin Yes, the "short version" has issues in terms of readibility . Actually it's only good for showing a way to represent AoAoA concisely. Other than that it's unusable because I can no longer index the elements as I can in an array :(